# Как округлить даты до начала недели?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Тип данных :

```
date_firs_dep           575 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

Пробую:

```
data4['min_date'] = data4['date_firs_dep'].round('W')
```

Ошибка:

> an integer is required (got type str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте модификатор, нужный, чтобы использовать соответствующие функции на сериях. Для дат это `dt`, для строк `str`:

```
data4['min_date'] = data4['date_firs_dep'].dt.round('W')

                                          ^^^^
```

Comment: <Week: weekday=6> is a non-fixed frequency  @CrazyElf

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Дальше сходу не подскажу, на английском SO про эту ошибку много понаписано

Comment: @ElenaBarbanova Попробуйте в конце после round добавить ещё `.dt.to_timestamp()`, вдруг получится

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

Исходный фрейм:

```
In [36]: df
Out[36]:
   date_firs_dep
0     2020-01-01
1     2020-01-02
2     2020-01-03
3     2020-01-04
4     2020-01-05
5     2020-01-06
6     2020-01-07
7     2020-01-08
8     2020-01-09
9     2020-01-10
10    2020-01-11
11    2020-01-12
12    2020-01-13
13    2020-01-14
```

решение:

```
df['min_date'] = df['date_firs_dep'] - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=0)
```

результат:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
   date_firs_dep   min_date
0     2020-01-01 2019-12-30
1     2020-01-02 2019-12-30
2     2020-01-03 2019-12-30
3     2020-01-04 2019-12-30
4     2020-01-05 2019-12-30
5     2020-01-06 2019-12-30
6     2020-01-07 2020-01-06
7     2020-01-08 2020-01-06
8     2020-01-09 2020-01-06
9     2020-01-10 2020-01-06
10    2020-01-11 2020-01-06
11    2020-01-12 2020-01-06
12    2020-01-13 2020-01-06
13    2020-01-14 2020-01-13
```